# preg_match ID in URL

Tags: php, url, parameters, preg-replace

Edit:
Sorry I wasnt very clear with my first post. Ok I have text stored in the database, Id like to process it and look for any links to the products on my site and turn them into a fancy link. Below is 2 links and my current exp. The second link (Link2) Works as expected and passes the value 21 to detailsLink() My problem lies with Link1 it passes the value of 2 to detailsLink() not 21 as expected. I want to disregard the url completely as detailsLink() recreates the link with the product rating/cat etc. It should also work on http or https links.

Link1: http://192.168.2.22/dev/details.php?id=21
Link2: http://192.168.2.22/dev/details.php?id=21&module=info#Desc

```
$s = preg_replace("%(?<![=\]\'\"\w])https?://[^<>\s\'\",]*$ADDRESS\/details\.php\?id=([0-9]+)[^<>\s\'\",]+%ie", "detailsLink(\\1)", $s);
```

the value of $ADDRESS is 192.168.2.22/dev

Comment: Please do not use the e(val) modifier but use `preg_replace_callback` instead.

Comment: And please don't re-invent the wheel with regex. Functions to parse the query-info-part of an URL are already available in PHP. See [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Answer (score 5):

No need to reinvent the wheel:

```
$url="http://192.168.2.22/dev/details.php?id=21&module=info#Desc";

parse_str(parse_url($url,PHP_URL_QUERY), $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

gives you:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 21
    [module] => info
)
```

[parse_str()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)
[parse_url()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand. Why don't you just use `$_GET['id']`?

EDIT: Never mind. I never knew about those functions! (parse_url, that is)

Comment: Probably because it's not the current page's URL.

Comment: That's what I originally thought but the question is worded in a very confusing way.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt very Clear, This is some user posted text stored in the database that im processing to display on site and I want to transform any product links found in the text into a fancy link.